# Mapping between two Extjs grid

Tags: extjs3

I am trying to map two Extjs grids in a single page, such that updating a first extjs grid will update the rows of second grid.
Till now i am maintening mapping by having an additional column in first grid which contains string of all data of corresponding row (separated by 4 hashes), **but each time a row updated in first grid adds a new row in second grid** which i need to change. Such that updating will also delete corresponding rows in second grid

Kindly help on urgent basis :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution...

Created one more column in grid 2 that will store the index of row of grid 1 that we are updating using  var item = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelected();